# Why python Script is Running from Local IP but giving error with IIS Configured IP?

Tags: python, pandas, vba, iis

Python Script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

path =r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VBA\batch_script\VBA Script.xlsm"

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path)
sheet.Application.Run("create.gen_report")
sheet.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

i was running the above script from python console, there were no errors. Then i tried running the same script with iis configured Ip 20.6.1:8089 by calling an API  from postman i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\python_scripts\runvba.py", line 155, in vba_run
    sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VBA\\batch_script\\VBA Script.xlsm'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I do not see any problem with path, then i tried running the Same API with localhost 127.0.0.1:5000, it was running fine with local Ip but not running from 20.6.1:8089.I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean "run from 20.6.1:8090"? Did you place a same application on server to run it? It seems that 20.6.1 is not a correct format of IP address.

Comment: @BruceZhang IP Address is correct , it is calling my function perfectly but the problem is, when i am calling the same with 20.6.1:8090 it is calling my function, but it is unable to access the file in the location, whereas when i am calling my Api with the local host. it is working fine. I am confused what is the problem.

Comment: Error message shows that it maybe a permission issue. Have you tried to change the path of xlsm file? Because the wwwroot folder requires more permissions than other folders, it may be that the CGI or application pool permissions are insufficient.